# .net compiler error “Not all code paths return a value” on Task method

Tags: .net, asynchronous, while-loop, compiler-errors, task

I have learned in practice how Task works in .net but I am still little bit confused with some aspects in the meaning of it. 
While refactoring an old code I just happened to have the following unfinished piece of code in one of my classes:

```
    private Task StartDataCollection()
    {
         // Some other code here but no Task.Run()
    }
```

And ofcourse the compiler complains:

> Error CS0161 ...  : not all code paths return a value

Then I added a while loop to the code as below and the compiler error is gone:

```
    private Task StartDataCollection()
    {
         while(true)
         {
         }
    }
```

Just for curiosity I changed the while loop like below and compiler complains for the same error again:

```
    private Task StartDataCollection()
    {
         while(false)
         {
         }
    }
```

And this is what really confuses me. If the compiler throws the Error CS0161 because there is no return statement (or something else as Task.Run()) then why a while(true) can fix it? Does it mean that a while(true) loop in the background runs a Task? I don't think so....Maybe I am missing a point here.

Comment: Note: this is *not* how you would typically write and initiate a background worker, if that is your intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real meaning of CS0161 isn't really "does every possible code path return a value", but rather: "is there a code path that somehow reaches the end of the method and *does not* return a value". The compiler is cleverly detecting that `while (true)` without a `break` is a loop that can't be exited to continue *after* the `while`, so: there is no way of reaching the end of the method. So: it isn't doing anything wrong *from the compiler's perspective*.

It is still very wrong, of course.

Note: if you add:

```cs
static bool AlwaysTrue() => true;
```

and change to `while (AlwaysTrue())`, it will now give you a CS0161 error, because this detection of a non-exited loop is specific to constant expressions that it can trivially evaluate as `true`.

It has nothing to do with running a `Task` in the background. It would do the same if you had an `int` or `string` as a return type.

---

Similarly, it will give you a CS0162 warning (unreachable code detected) if you do:

```cs
while (false)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hi");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc for your explanation. The only thing I still have hard time to understand is why the following code compiles:

    private Task StartDataCollection()
    {
         while(true)
         {
         }
    }

but not without the while(true) loop.

Comment: @RaminToussi again: show me a semantically valid code path where it reaches the end of the method without returning a value - there *isn't one*, because the compiler knows that a `while(true)` loop without a `break` never exits to go *beyond* the `while`